# Accessing Variable within a method within a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, methods

New to Python - I have been trying to access a variable that is contained in a method within a method. I have looked at the class Documentation and previous stack overflow questions and I cannot find anything that is helping me with my situation.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    def quarter(self):            
        def third():
            double = self.num1 * 2
            third  = self.num2 / 3

            return double, triple
class1 = MyClass(2, 3)


print(class1.quarter.......
```

Obviously I would like to print this information out, but cannot access it. How do I do this?

Comment: That is just a normal function in your method, and you never do anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way to access your `third` function outside of `quarter`. This means that you need to return it:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
    def quarter(self):            
        def third():
            double = self.num1 * 2
            triple  = self.num2 / 3
            return double, triple
        return third
class1 = MyClass(2, 3)
```

When you call `quarter` you will get a function, which you can call like this

```
print(class1.quarter()())
```

Comment: Understood - I have never seen that with the double parentheses before. Thank you